# GoogleMaps - show location based on city and street

Tags: google-maps

Greetings, 
In my page I would like to display a google map with the location of companies. I have the following credentials for company:
City, Street
How can I display the map having by using these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will help you some more or if you change your address into lat and long using geocode api you can mark them easily .

check out the url below

http://www.aspstarterkit.com/wp-content/Geocoding_Marker_Example.zip

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 **Easy way - no programming** --> quick, best for a map with a predefined set of companies

- on Google Maps click on My Maps in the left column and them "Create new map"
- in the top left corner You'll see markers, lines and area controls to put on the map
- find the address in the search field, put the marker on the place + you can add the description (Company Name & the street) in the balloon
- click Done
- find the Link in the top right corner and customize the link to embed Your map in a website

2 **Flexible way - simple Javascript**--> a little longer, best for a map that will dynamically display changing set of companies

- learn the Google Maps API on Geocoding: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/services.html#Geocoding (you can get something like in [the example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/examples/geocoding-simple.html))
- create Your Javascript to set the map